# How to support 18.5:9 aspect ratio?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aspect-ratio

I can't build apk to it supported **18.5:9** aspect ratio. Now it shows black lines at top and bottom:

[image: Screenshot]

The camera is cleared by a white color so black lines are not a problem of the canvas settings or some other game object.
Also I set **PlayerSettings -> Aspect ratio mode** to **Native aspect ratio** and checked the **Start in fullscreen mode** flag.

**P.S.** I use **Unity 2018.3.11f1**.

**ADDED**
It's not a problem of UI elements on **Canvas** because of the splash and all scenes is shown with black gaps. Also before I hadn't it, this bug happened when I've updated from **Unity 2018.3.10f1** to **Unity 2018.3.11f1** and added this loader scene to select language, maybe I changed yet something I don't know because of I found this bag much later when I tested the game on **18.5:9** device.

**P.P.S.** If it's important I use **Android build-tools 29.0.0-rc2**, **Android NDK r16b** and set **Android Pie** as target platform.

Comment: Create an image in your canvas that will serve as a container to these buttons, make it fit the whole screen in the rectTransform component, switch its color to white and then finally take the buttons and move them inside of this container

Comment: @IdoBenShalom thank you very much! I will try today, hope it will help. But honestly, I still can't get why does canvas influence on the camera aspect ratio?..

Comment: @IdoBenShalom, it didn't help. Even splash screen is not fullscreen still.